# Filter or conditional statement on a simple document?

Tags: jmespath

On the below simple JSON document

```
{ "result" : 5 }
```

I would like to filter or apply a condition in order to get value matching `result > 5`

Answer (score 0):

JMESPath is not really meant to act on a single object.

In order to achieve this, though, you can convert the object to an array, with the function [`to_array`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array) and back to an object, using `| [0]`, in order to extract back the first element of the list, as explained in [working with nested data](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#working-with-nested-data).

All together, this gives the query:

```
to_array(@)[?result>`5`] | [0]
```

- Which, on the JSON:

  ```json
  { "result" : 5 }
  ```

  gives:

  ```json
  null
  ```
- And, on the JSON:

  ```json
  { "result" : 6 }
  ```

  gives:

  ```json
  {
    "result": 6
  }
  ```